# Regexp_replace processing result

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string with groups of nubmers. And Id like to make constant length string. Now I use two regexp_replace. First to add 10 numbers to string and next to cut string and take last 10 values:

```
with s(txt) as ( select '1030123:12031:1341' from dual)
select regexp_replace(
       regexp_replace(txt, '(\d+)','0000000000\1')
,'\d+(\d{10})','\1') from s ;
```

But Id like to use only one regex something like

```
regexp_replace(txt, '(\d+)',lpad('\1',10,'0'))
```

But it don't work. lpad executed before regexp. Could you have any ideas?

Comment: Is it always the same number of groups, i.e. 3?

Comment: No. Now it may be any count of groups from 1 to 5. But I want to make solution for any count of groups

Answer (score 1):

With a slightly different approach, you can try the following:

```
with s(id, txt) as
(
    select rownum, txt
    from (
            select '1030123:12031:1341' as txt from dual union all
            select '1234:0123456789:1341' from dual
         )
)                 
SELECT listagg(lpad(regexp_substr(s.txt, '[^:]+', 1, lines.column_value), 10, '0'), ':') within group (order by column_value) txt
 FROM s,
   TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
   (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY instr(s.txt, ':', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
   ) AS sys.odciNumberList )) lines
group by id

TXT
-----------------------------------
0001030123:0000012031:0000001341
0000001234:0123456789:0000001341
```

This uses the `CONNECT BY` to split every string based on the separator `':'`, then uses `LPAD` to pad to 10 and then aggregates the strings to build rows containing the concatenation of padded values

Comment: Thank you. I think about it. But in a big table It will be too expensive

Comment: And in your result groups are mixed

Answer (score 0):

This works for non-empty sequences (e.g. 123::456)

```
with s(txt) as ( select '1030123:12031:1341' from dual)

select    regexp_replace (regexp_replace (txt,'(\d+)',lpad('0',10,'0') || '\1'),'0*(\d{10})','\1')

from      s
;
```

Comment: But its the same as my current solution?

Comment: You have an empty space here:    '\d+ (\d{10})

Comment: @Zhenora , Hi, since this was a right answer, do you mind  marking it as a correct answer?

Comment: Yes its right answer, but it the same as mine. two regexp_replace with taking ends

Comment: @Zhenora, yours didn't work and this is why you've posted this question. You fixed it after I pointed to you where the error is, even that it was a very small error. I'm leaving you the chice to decide if to aknowledge that or not. In any case I'm glad I could help.